# SQL Counting shifts worked by each employee for each day of the week

Tags: sql

I want to build a query that shows how many times my employees work each day. For example, I want to show that over a period of time, Jim worked 12 Saturdays, 3 Mondays, and a Thursday. I plan to do this through pulling the weekday datepart from the time-clock entries. I just don't know how to build it such that there are seven conditional count columns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Add some example to your question. You can insert case into your count to make conditional count, for example: sum(case when day_column = 'wednesday' then 1 else 0 end)

Answer (score 0):

Making a lot of assumptions:

1. "TimeCard" is your table
2. EmployeeID is your identifier for the employee
3. You have 1 time record per an employee per day
4. The day the employee worked is name [timestamp]

```
select 
    EmployeeID,
    count(case when datepart(weekday, [timestamp]) = 1 then 1 end) as [Sunday],
    count(case when datepart(weekday, [timestamp]) = 2 then 1 end) as [Monday],
    count(case when datepart(weekday, [timestamp]) = 3 then 1 end) as [Tuesday],
    count(case when datepart(weekday, [timestamp]) = 4 then 1 end) as [Wednesday],
    count(case when datepart(weekday, [timestamp]) = 5 then 1 end) as [Thursday],
    count(case when datepart(weekday, [timestamp]) = 6 then 1 end) as [Friday],
    count(case when datepart(weekday, [timestamp]) = 7 then 1 end) as [Saturday]
from [TimeCard]
group by EmployeeID
```

Comment: Thank you Dave, your answer has pointed me in the right direction. It all boiled down to Count(case), which I am not as familiar with, and will now learn more about. 

Thank you again, your answer helped so much!